# CSS -- linear-gradient working in chrome - but not in other browsers?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

The below code is working only for firefox.

What should I need to change to work in all browsers....

```
background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #E6E6E9) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

Any advices will be thankful and grateful.....

Answer (score 1):

As some of the old browsers still need vendor prefix, so you'll probably need `-webkit` for chrome or `-o` for opera, `-moz` for firefox etc... Check the below link, you'll get total cross-browser gradient syntax

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

linear-gradient isn't fully cross-browser compatible; instead it has browser specific prefix's (`-o`, `-moz`,`-webkit` etc.)

I suggest using a tool like [this one](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to create CSS gradients, and it's all done for you!